# Handling paths with whitespace that result from a backtick command

Tags: bash, unix

Trying to remove certain folders from my directory tree.

```
rm -r `find -name .sbas`
```

For some folders it fails like this:

```
rm: cannot remove ‘./Reports/Report’: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ‘11/.sbas’: No such file or directory
```

The whitespace in the folder path is confusing the command into thinking it's getting two different paths.

What's the best way to handle this? Removing the whitespace from the folder names is not an option.

Comment: This kind of operation is quite dangerous. You should be very careful with it. There's a variety of things that'll break horribly when doing that. The spaces you noted  - but there's a few filenames that can also end up doing horrible things.

Comment: Thanks for the note. I knew it was risky but I tried `find | rm` which didn't work so it was the only thing I knew how to do. Luckily I know a better way know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use output of `find` in `rm` like that.

Use `find -delete`:

```
find . -name .sbas -delete
```

Or on systems where `find` doesn't support `delete` use:

```
find . -name .sbas -exec rm -r '{}' \;
```